# Distance between a matrix and it inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

It is know that the product of a matrix $A$ and its inverse is identity matrix. Is there a distance measure between inverse of a matrix and another matrix. For example if $A$ is a matrix I want to find a distance for a matrix $B$ to inverse of $A$. I know the possible norms of a matrix and hence possible distance between two matrices. But I am wondering is there a very specific measure for Inverse? What I am looking for is a to analyse a measure which deviate fast from the true inverse. What I mean by deviate fast is that a measure which will clearly distinguish the true Inverse from the other matrices.

Comment: How about simply computing $\|1-BA\|$ for some matrix norm?

Comment: @H.H.Rugh I tried  that in the first place, but sharpness was not as I expected; what I mean is the norm difference between actual inverse and other matrix was not high.

Comment: Could the 'typical' matrix $A$ be close to  singular? Can it have very large/small elements? (if you happen to know). And what do you consider as 'sharp'? For ex, $\|1-BA\|=10^{-3}$ is that close?

Comment: @H.H.Rugh yes, the norm you said is very close. It might help to mention that my matrix $A$ is an convolution operator. So I guess I am working on a very specific area.

Comment: ok, but convolution (e.g with Green's functions) tends to be close to compact and then having rather singular inverse. Also I gather that your dimension is very high.

Comment: @H.H.Rugh, correct. Dimension is high, but with noise the measure is not as sharp as i expected.

Comment: If the kernel is not symmetric then a possibly silly idea: To calculate $\|1-AB\|+\|1-BA\|$. Reason: When $A$ is close to singular, a large error in $B$ may map into that kernel and go unnoticed in $\|1-AB\|$ but may be captured by $\|1-BA\|$ (and similar reason for the other way around). Perhaps you could add a  more precise description of your kernel to the post? Who knows. That may give ideas about how to proceed?

Comment: @H.H.Rugh It may sound unusual but kernel is derived from narrow-band compact sinusoidal..

Comment: Meaning that you are doing something like noise-reduction in frequency modulation on a time-series? This may be an injective map but it certainly looks close to being singular. So $B$ will in general be quite 'large' I suppose (if it exists)

Comment: @H.H.Rugh sorry, may i ask what you mean by large?

Comment: If $A$ has eigenvalues, say of the form $1/k^2$, $k=1,2,3,4,...$ then $B$ will have eigenvalues $k^2$, $k=1,2,3,4,...$ so necessarily have large elements. But probably more efficient if you wrote another post (or reedited the present) and gave a more explicit description of your 'kernel' and perhaps also explain why you want to invert?

Answer (score 3):

No single norm is "preferred" for computing $\Vert A^{-1} - B \Vert$. You might choose a norm based on your particular application, or to achieve a certain result.

---

However, note that $\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ forms a finite dimensional vector space, and hence all  norms on $\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ are *equivalent*. That is, if $|\cdot|$ and $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ are norms, there exist positive constants $c$ and $c^\prime$ such that

$$c | X | \leq \Vert X \Vert \leq c^\prime |X| \text{ for all } X \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}.$$

A consequence of this is that if you have a sequence $\{B_n\}$ which converges to $A^{-1}$ in one norm, it converges in any norm. That is to say (very roughly)...

> if $B_n$ gets close to $A^{-1}$ in one norm, it gets close to $A^{-1}$ in any other norm.

This might inadvertently answer your question.

---

**Note**: I used $\mathbb{C}$ for simplicity, but you do not have to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is very helpful. Can the convergence property be different for different norm? For example the rate of convergence or behavior of the norm close to point of convergence?

Answer (score 2):

I think, there is not a particular distance for inverse pairs, which is not one of the norms you mentioned. You could consider the [Frobenius distance](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusNorm.html) between two matrices $A$ and $B$. Of course, there are many other possibilities: if the matrices are $\mathbf{A} = (a_{ij})$ and $\mathbf{B} = (b_{ij})$, then some examples are:
$$
d_1(\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B}) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n |a_{ij} - b_{ij}|
$$
$$
d_2(\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B}) = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n (a_{ij} - b_{ij})^2}
$$
$$
d_\infty(\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B}) = \max_{1 \le i \le n}\max_{1 \le j \le n} |a_{ij} - b_{ij}|
$$
$$
d_m(\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B}) = \max\{ \|(\mathbf{A} - \mathbf{B})\mathbf{x}\| : \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n, \|\mathbf{x}\| = 1 \}
$$